# Why does the soundcloud stream URL is not permanent? I get 403 Forbidden error when try to play the stream again after a few minutes

Tags: stream, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to stream soundcloud tracks in my own player using the API and it plays the first time I make the request but after a few minutes if I try to stream from the same URL I get 403 error "Forbidden". Does the stream URL expire?

Comment: Probably exactly as a security feature so people don't hotlink their files... And yes the URLs contain a key, which probably gets invalid after some time.

Comment: Yes I want to save the link in a list of the player for playing them later.
Is there any particular way to get a permanent link to the track?